# How to connect to an existing serverless deploy

Tags: serverless-framework

Say I am working on one computer, and I do a `serverless deploy`. And lets say for arguments sake that I toss my computer out the window out of anger, and buy another. Is there any way when I start working on my `serverless` project to connect to the existing deployed version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as you still have access to the serverless.yml and any source code (cause you checked it into source control or backed it up somewhere) and you still have credentials for the AWS account the serverless app is deployed to, sure

Comment: Question is how, not if.

Comment: Checkout/copy/whatever the serverless project code to your new computer. Setup your new computer with the AWS credentials that have access to the account the serverless app is deployed to. Run serverless deploy. See https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/credentials/ for all the various ways you can setup AWS credentials to work with serverless

Comment: This assumes you are using AWS, but Azure, GCP would work the same way

Comment: But am I going to connect to the same deployed serverless app when I do this that I was working on with my old computer?

Comment: Yes. The credentials will give you access to the same cloud provider account and serverless.yml will reference the same resources within the account